# camera clipping settings not extending far enough

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Blender 2.8. MAC

I created a straight cyc wall and I'm rotating doing about a 35degree camera rotation around an object.  No matter how big I make the camera clipping end point the wall clips on the ends.  Currently it's set to 10000 but there's no change with any number bigger than 250.  I can see the correct wall end in viewport but not in camera view and not in renders.  I place a monkey head on the edge of where it clips. [image: This shot shows where the edge is in viewport]

[image: This shot shows were the clip is in camera view and render]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

There's actually 2 different clip distance settings. One is for the viewport, but the camera also has its own separate clip distance, which is probably set too low.

With the camera selected, you can find this in the camera tab of the properties panel.

[image]

Comment: Yes that was it.  Thanks.  I'm a video editor and learning Blender was my Covid Project.  While I'm just scratching the surface, I have been able to import models from a client, add materials,  light the scene and do some animation and use those animation in my video projects.    THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer is correct, please accept it using the check mark that can be found on the left side of the answer (under the votes). Otherwise the question is still considered unresolved.